# Adding a custom Icon to the Inbox summary using office js

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Good Day to all.

I have developed an outlook addin that allows users to save emails and/or attachments to Aws S3. It works well. However, I'd like to add a custom icon to the inbox summary list when an Item has been saved?

I have read through the office js API and cannot find anything that would allow this. However, I wanted to check with the community before giving up.

Cheers

[Outlook inbox summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbygG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the feature to add a custom icon to the inbox summary list, that you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Comment: link is dead...